# Building Project that uses EntityFramework fails with a lot of errors

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, ado.net, entity-framework-6

I am using EntityFramework as my Data Access Layer in a Visual Studio C# project. I have added a new entity model and built right away without adding or doing anything to test its functionality. Unfortunately, the build failed with many errors like:

```
CS0426  The type name 'Data' does not exist in the type 'System'
CS0138  A 'using namespace' directive can only be applied to namespaces; 'System' is a type not a namespace. Consider a 'using static' directive instead    
CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Nullable<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

The code editor itself appears as though it is missing something even though every thing is in place

[image]
[image]

The pictures show both the editor and the references that I have in my project

P.S: The project type is Class Library

Comment: What is the 'Target framework' of that project? Did you try right click on Solution -> Clean, then right click -> Rebuild All?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, it is all my mistake. I had a table in the Database called "Systems" and when `Entity Framework` turned the plural into singular it became "System" class which caused confusion and ambiguity to the compiler. Consequently, the compiler could not correctly resolve the type.

Comment: Yeah, I've had this before myself. You have to be careful with entity names and trying to avoid any system namespace class names as otherwise it can get very confused.