# Local database, Entity Framework and WinForms

Tags: .net, winforms, entity-framework

**Using: Visual Studio 2017; EF 6; vb.net**

I'm new to EF. My database knowledge is middling, although I'm poor at the technicalities. I am trying to use EF with a winforms project. Because it's a new project, I'm going for 'Model First.' I've managed to get a .edmx model up and running and have successfully "Generate[d] database from model" to a local Microsoft MySQL server db via "(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDb" as the server name.

This is my first question:

1) Given that this is going to be a desktop app, I couldn't find the .mdf file in the project folder. How would this work on deployment? Do I have to copy this file into the project folder so it's built into the deployment folder?

My second problem is more severe. Once I have done this, the database appears to have been set up correctly (if I browse it via Server Explorer, I can see the new tables corresponding to the entities). I can also find the new classes corresponding to the entities via Object Explorer (although I can't see any .tt files or other class files relating to these in Solution explorer - like in older videos and guides).

The problem is, whereas it would build and run before generating the database, now there are a raft of errors around the form code. It appears to have been modified. What is more, if you add another form, it also shows further errors. The vanilla modified form:

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class MainForm
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        components = New System.ComponentModel.Container
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(800, 450)
        Me.Text = "MainForm"
    End Sub
End Class
```

And the raft of errors:

[image]

### Edit

Updated shot of bug ridden form code and references following comments below:

[image]

(the redacting is due to my using an expletive to describe EF!)

Comment: You need to add a reference to System.Windows.Forms. What kind of application template did you select when starting your dev efforts?

Comment: Well, it was initialised as a winforms app, so it's not that. Just tried to be sure - made no difference at all. Weird how it just breaks it. Not enjoying EF so far... thought it was meant to make things easier? o.O

Comment: Are you sure that the System.Windows.Forms reference is present under the References node of your project? This error is reproducible building an empty windows forms application and then removing the reference. (as well System.Drawing for Size property)

Comment: All there. See updated post above..

Answer (score 0):

Unbelievable. It transpires that if your have one of your tables/entities named as "System" or "Systems" then this throws a spanner in the works via namespaces. Changed and no more errors. Thanks microsoft for wasting a day of my life. Can't believe there's not a catch/fail-safe on that...

as per this post, here:
[building-project-that-uses-entityframework-fails-with-a-lot-of-errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42159307/building-project-that-uses-entityframework-fails-with-a-lot-of-errors)